# È corretta l'espressione "il doppio più lunga delle altre"?

Tags: adjectives, numbers, phrase-choice, comparison

Ho testé sentito in un telefilm la frase

> Ha presentato una lista **il doppio più lunga delle altre**

A me verrebbe più naturale dire "lunga il doppio delle altre", e assumo che questa sia l'espressione più usata.

Detto questo, mi chiedo se "il doppio più lunga delle altre" sia considerabile proprio errata (come penso), o sia comunque accettabile, sebbene meno usata.

Comment: _(non avevo idea di come taggare, sentitevi liberi di ritaggare, in caso)_

Comment: Credo che l'espressione sia corretta e anche di uso comune. È però una costruzione che oggettivamente potrebbe prestarsi a degli equivoci tecnici: è più lunga del 100% o del 200%? Se x è 100 e y è 200 allora y è il doppio di x ma non necessariamente il doppio più grande di x ("il doppio più grande" potrebbe intendersi 300, cioè 100 più il doppio di 100). A meno che non si tratti semplicemente di un'iperbole, è raccomandabile esprimersi con più precisione.

Comment: Tutte e due le espressioni citate mi sembrano corrette, anche se "il doppio più..." mi suona più colloquiale. È anche vero che seppur madrelingua, non parlo italiano da ormai troppi anni...

Comment: @randomatlabuser sì, è principalmente questa considerazione che mi ha confuso in primo luogo. Purtroppo è un errore comune, commesso in genere da parte di chi non è molto portato per i numeri...

Comment: @Lohoris Visto che mi sembra che il mio commento risponda alla tua domanda lo sposto in risposta.

Comment: @randomatlabuser attendo qualche giorno prima di accettarla, che magari arriva qualche altro parere.

Comment: Lohoris, I've changed the tags, no problem. When choosing a tag for the future questions, please remember to [use _English_ tags](http://meta.italian.stackexchange.com/questions/7/what-language-should-we-use-for-tags).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Credo che l'espressione sia corretta e anche di uso comune. Con ogni probabilità il significato *inteso* è che la lista è più lunga delle altre fino ad arrivare ad una lunghezza doppia rispetto all[a media dell]e altre.

È tuttavia una costruzione che oggettivamente potrebbe prestarsi a degli equivoci tecnici: è più lunga del 100%, e quindi arriva complessivamente al doppio, o è più lunga del 200% (il doppio), e quindi arriva complessivamente al triplo?

Se x è 100 e y è 200 allora y è il **doppio di x** ma non necessariamente il **doppio più grande di x**: "il doppio più grande" potrebbe intendersi il triplo, 300, cioè 100 più il doppio di 100.

Quindi sono d'accordo con Lohoris: a meno che non si tratti semplicemente di un'iperbole, è raccomandabile esprimersi con più precisione.

Answer (score 4):

Quanto alla diffusione di queste e simili espressioni, una misura indicativa la dà il numero di risposte di Google:

**A.** *"il doppio più lunga":* 48.900;

**B.** *"lunga il doppio":*  177.000;

**C.** *"due volte più lunga":*  2.240.000;

**D.** *"lunga due volte":*  114.000.

Il numero così alto di risultati per la forma **C** è un po' sospetto e forse dipende da motivi contingenti; però provando con altri aggettivi mi pare che l'ordine sia sempre: **A, D, B**  in ragione circa 1/2/3 e poi la **C** almeno dieci o venti volte più frequente delle altre (ecco che l'ho usata anche io ora senza farci caso).

Sospetto perciò che la poca fortuna della forma **A**, in particolare rispetto alla  **C**, grammaticalmente molto vicina, sia di natura fonetica. La ripetizione balbettante della *p* rafforzata in *doppioppiù* è indubbiamente cacofonica.